# MySQL Select when specific digit is x

Tags: mysql

I have a column that contains values like 5A898, 89KAS, 89ASD.

I'm trying to write a query that will only return rows where the third digit of the column is 'A'.  For instance '89ASD' would be returned but '89KAS' would not.  I'm not sure what the right way to go about this is. Regular expressions?

So...

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE column = ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE column LIKE '__A%'
                   ^^-- 2 underscores
```

should do the trick. two "whatever" characters, followed by an A, then followed by anything in any amount.

Comment: How efficient would this be versus `SUBSTRING(column, 3, 1) = 'A'` ?

Comment: about the same. since you're using wildcards and derived values, neither will allow indexes to be used.

Comment: Agreed, but surely pattern matching carries some significant overhead versus directly accessing the third character of a string?

Comment: depends on how smart the query optimizer is. `__` is fairly easy to handle. doing `%A%` would be a bit heavier.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING(column,3,1) = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where right(left(col,3),1) = 'A'
```

That can help... MarcB's answer is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex, but I think it might be easier just coping with a string operation here:

```
SELECT column
FROM   table
WHERE  SUBSTRING(column,3,1) = 'A';
```